# React Native Android App crashing with "E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: mqt_native_modules"

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-firebase, react-native-maps

Crash my app after install and config `react-native-maps` and `@react-native-firebase/app` in existing projects.

#### Environment info

```sh
OS: Windows 10
CPU: (4) x64 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7500U CPU @ 2.70GHz
Memory: 2.08 GB / 11.90 GB
Binaries:
Node: 10.16.0 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.EXE
Yarn: 1.9.4 - C:\Program Files (x86)\Yarn\bin\yarn.CMD
npm: 6.9.0 - C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm.CMD
SDKs:
Android SDK:
  API Levels: 23, 25, 26, 27, 28
  Build Tools: 23.0.1, 25.0.1, 25.0.2, 25.0.3, 26.0.1, 26.0.2, 26.0.3, 27.0.3, 28.0.1, 28.0.2, 28.0.3
  System Images: android-23 | Intel x86 Atom_64, android-23 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-23 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom_64, android-26 | Google APIs Intel x86 Atom, android-28 | Intel x86 Atom_64, android-28 | Google Play Intel x86 Atom
IDEs:
Android Studio: Version  3.5.0.0 AI-191.8026.42.35.5900203
npmPackages:
react: 16.9.0 => 16.9.0
react-native: 0.61.4 => 0.61.4
```

Part of my app dependencies:

```sh
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^6.0.3",
"react-native-maps": "0.26.1",
```

#### Steps To Reproduce

I did a debug through the `Aandroid studio` and get following error

> --------- beginning of crash
>   11-13 15:00:24.209 4709-4746/com.melk.android E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: mqt_native_modules
>       Process: com.melk.android, PID: 4709
>       java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions
>           at com.airbnb.android.react.maps.AirMapManager.(AirMapManager.java:60)
>           at com.airbnb.android.react.maps.MapsPackage.createViewManagers(MapsPackage.java:40)
>           at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.getOrCreateViewManagers(ReactInstanceManager.java:782)
>           at com.facebook.react.CoreModulesPackage.createUIManager(CoreModulesPackage.java:184)
>           at com.facebook.react.CoreModulesPackage.getModule(CoreModulesPackage.java:152)
>           at com.facebook.react.TurboReactPackage$ModuleHolderProvider.get(TurboReactPackage.java:122)
>           at com.facebook.react.TurboReactPackage$ModuleHolderProvider.get(TurboReactPackage.java:110)
>           at com.facebook.react.bridge.ModuleHolder.create(ModuleHolder.java:188)
>           at com.facebook.react.bridge.ModuleHolder.getModule(ModuleHolder.java:153)
>           at com.facebook.react.bridge.NativeModuleRegistry.getModule(NativeModuleRegistry.java:148)
>           at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.getNativeModule(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:479)
>           at com.facebook.react.bridge.CatalystInstanceImpl.getNativeModule(CatalystInstanceImpl.java:466)
>           at com.facebook.react.uimanager.UIManagerHelper.getUIManager(UIManagerHelper.java:31)
>           at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.attachRootViewToInstance(ReactInstanceManager.java:1054)
>           at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.setupReactContext(ReactInstanceManager.java:1012)
>           at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager.access$1400(ReactInstanceManager.java:125)
>           at com.facebook.react.ReactInstanceManager$5$2.run(ReactInstanceManager.java:972)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>           at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:26)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>           at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$4.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:225)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)

#### Reproducible sample code

`android/build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 16
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2")

        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue : this issue is seen when your fresco library version is not matching with animated-gif or any other library for instance.

Solution-1 :
(My requirement was to use animatied-gif library, so my version is same for fresco and animated-gif.i.e it should be same for your respective version)

implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:2.6.0'

implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:animated-gif:2.6.0'

Solution-2 : (Only for suggestion, don't use)

Downgrade one version of your react-native version. [I will request you to use solution only as mentioned above]